# Why image is not scaling to NSImageView

Tags: swift, image, nsimageview

I have this fragment of code in my app

```
imvPallet.frame = NSRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 200, height: 150)
imvPallet.imageScaling = .scaleAxesIndependently
self.view.addSubview(imvPallet)
imvPallet.image = NSImage(named: "Pallet")
```

where imvPallet is NSImageView object and Pallet is PNG image with original size 779 × 518 pixels stored in app's Assets.
Image is still displayed in fixed original size regardless of imvPallet.frame dimension and various scaling parameters. My aim is to always fit image to imvPallet.frame size.
Thanks for hints.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "My aim is to always fit image to imvPallet.frame size"?

Comment: I wanna change imvPallet.frame size programatically and manage image size accordingly in a way that it's always fully shown in ImageView.

Comment: What do you mean by "fully shown"?  You mean, stretch the image if necessary?

Comment: Yes, stretch = always fill ImageView frame as much is possible and always show whole image.

Comment: Then it's just the matter of resizing the image according to the image view, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed, so I did it directly via image.size. I thought it could be done to change ImageView.frame size somehow.

Comment: You are not dealing with the `UIImageClass`.  That's not how the `NSImageView` works.

Comment: I tried your code and the image is scaled to fit the image view. How is `imvPallet` created? Post a [mre] please.

Comment: ImageView is created in IB

Answer (score -1):

Try to *scaleProportionallyUpOrDown* for fit image to imvPallet

```
imvPallet.imageScaling = .scaleProportionallyUpOrDown
```